# ¿Cómo comprobar de dónde se envía por POST?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tengo un formulario hecho con **AngularJS** y tengo un archivo en el *servidor* que recibe dicho formulario enviado por `POST`, quiero saber cómo evitar que desde un formulario igual al mío que apunte a ese archivo **PHP** puedan enviar información

Pensé en enviar una *clave* junto a los datos y enviarlo por `POST` pero al estar hecho en **AJAX** el `script` que lo envía, esta *clave* sería visible desde el navegador.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar mejor que es lo que intentas hacer y agregar el código que llevas para poder ayudarte mejor? De paso te animo a que te des una vuelta por el [tour] y [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un Token.

1.- Tu Php puede generar un token de acceso que dure X minutos.

2.- Ese token se lo pasas al Frontend (AngularJS).

3.- Entonces tu formulario de AngularJS (Angular 1) enviara los datos del formulario y el Token.

4.- Tu Php validara si el token que hizo la petición esta vigente (o caduco, según los minutos que le diste de vida). Y pues si es vigente que siga su proceso normal.

Te dejo un link interesante acerca de los token: http://www.notas-programacion.com/2014/10/generacion-de-tokens-de-seguridad-y-validacion-en-bd-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

De donde se realizó el post viene en la variable `$_SERVER`, pero la misma doumentación de php indica que puede ser modificada.
http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php

`echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

La solución propuesta por @ELM es correcta, es mejor generar tokens

```
$data['my_token'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$_SESSION['my_token'] = $data['my_token'];
```

sobre el html

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_token" id="my_token" value="<? php echo $_SESSION['my_token']?>" />
```

La verificación

```
if ($_POST['my_token'] === $_SESSION['my_token'])
{
        // was ok
}
else
{
          // was bad!!!
}
```

La solución esta en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466241/new-csrf-token-per-request-or-not